# Why I get don't care at clk_out?

Tags: asynchronous, verilog, system

I am getting X as **clk_out**.Example of the frequency divider.

```verilog
module freq_by2(input clk,rst,output reg clk_out);
  always @(posedge clk)
  begin
    if (rst==1'b1)
    begin
      clk_out<=0;
    end
    else
    begin
      clk_out<=~clk_out;
    end
  end
endmodule

module freq_by4(input clk,rst,output reg [1:0] clk_out);
  
  freq_by2 f0(.clk(clk),.rst(rst),.clk_out(clk_out[0]));
  freq_by2 f1(.clk(clk_out[0]),.rst(rst),.clk_out(clk_out[1]));
  
endmodule
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure, you are generating a correct, synchronous `rst` pulse? That is, synchronous to both clk and clk/2, because your `f1` instantiation is synchronous to the `clk_out` output of `f0`? Otherwise, you are negating the last value of `clk_out` inside of `freq_by2`, which is `X` initially, unless a correct reset was generated.